# JavaScript Morph Button

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I am trying to test this [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)code in my [sublimetext3](/questions/tagged/sublimetext3)using a chrome build, but I am failing in doing so. Whenever I build in [sublimetext3](/questions/tagged/sublimetext3)none of the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)code is working. I tested a simple alert code and it works fine. I have no luck when I insert this code though. The snippet is also working, so it must be on my end. Any ideas?

```js
var mail = document.getElementById('mail'),
  input = document.getElementById('input'),
  sendText = document.querySelectorAll('.send'),
  send = document.getElementById('send'),
  tick = document.getElementById('p2'),
  p1 = document.getElementById('p1');

send.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sendText[0].textContent = "Sent";
  p1.style.opacity = 0;
  tick.style.opacity = 1;
});


input.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  var email = this.value;
  openMail();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    closeMail();
  }
});

function openMail() {
  mail.setAttribute('points', "2.6,55.9 60.8,5.3 118.9,56.3");
  mail.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0,-53)');
}

function closeMail() {
  mail.setAttribute('points', "2.6,3.1 60.8,48.8 118.9,3.6");
  mail.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  var ex = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  return ex.test(email);
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700);
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #46cbda;
}

.subscribe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
}

.subscribe__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease, width 0.25s ease;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 88%;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 12%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;
  background: #ec1a01;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: width 0.1s ease;
}

button .send {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

button:hover {
  width: 26%;
}

button:hover .send {
  opacity: 1;
}

button:hover .divider {
  animation: divider 0.15s 0.2s linear forwards;
}

button:hover svg {
  width: 23px;
  transform: rotate(-18deg) translateX(10px) translateY(3px);
  z-index: 10;
}

.divider {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 50;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  background: #ec1a01;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

@keyframes divider {
  to {
    height: 60%;
  }
}

#p2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.more-concepts {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.more-concepts:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="subscribe">
    <div class="subscribe__wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="input" />
      <button id="send">
      <span class="divider"></span>
      <span class="send">Send</span>
      <svg width="122.6px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 122.6 77.9">
        <g id="p2" transform="scale(2)" fill="#fff">
          <path d="M62.4,6.9L23.6,45.7c-0.3,0.3-0.9,0.3-1.2,0L0.3,23.7c-0.3-0.3-0.3-0.9,0-1.2l5.4-5.4c0.3-0.3,0.9-0.3,1.2,0l16.1,16.1
 L55.8,0.3c0.3-0.3,0.9-0.3,1.2,0l5.4,5.4C62.8,6,62.8,6.5,62.4,6.9L62.4,6.9z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="p1">
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M113.6,8.1v61.8H8V8.1H113.6 M121.6,0.1H0v77.8h121.6V0.1L121.6,0.1z" />
          <polygon fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="9.9,73.1 60.8,48.8 115.5,73.1 " />
          <polyline id="mail" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="2.6,3.1 60.8,48.8 118.9,3.6 " />
          <polyline fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="5.4,6.9 60.8,48.8 115.5,6.9 " />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sublimetext 3 Chrome Build

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "$file"]
}
```

Comment: Upped for neatness

Comment: Can you also include information on how you're building this in Sublime, e.g. what package you're using and/or what the `sublime-build` file looks like?

Comment: Okay, I edited the message and added the build I use.

Comment: I don't do a lot of web dev, so apologies if this is a dumb observation, but it doesn't look like the HTML above is referencing the JavaScript code at all (like a `<script>` tag or whatever)?

Comment: All good, I added the <script> with the source leading to my .js file but no luck. The javascript alert is working fine, but this code isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I feel so foolish. I didn't properly place my script tag. I placed it in the beginning of my code, when it should have been placed after the elements that it was requesting.